# MVC Calculated field and field formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Sorry if my question is too basic, i'm just new to mvc with no experince in javascript.

1- I'm trying to add calculated field in my view with no success
I have the following class

```
public class TaxCalculation
{
  [Required]
  [DisplayName("Init")]
  [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}")]
  public double InitVlaue { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [DisplayName("Reg")]
  [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}")]
  public double RegValue { get; set; }

  [DisplayName("Enga")]
  [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}")]
  public double InitEnga
  {
    get { return CommonComputation.CalcuEnga(InitVlaue, RegValue); }
  }
}
```

**CommonComputation.CalcuEnga** function:

```
public static double CalcuEnga(double InitVlaue, double RegValue)
    {
        double V_Et = (0.02 * 0.225 - 1) * Math.Log(0.225 / (100 - 0.225));
        double V_En = (0.02 * 0.711 - 1) * Math.Log(0.711 / (100 - 0.711));
        double mk = Math.Round(RegValue / InitVlaue * 100, 3);
        double V_Ep = (0.02 * InitVlaue - 1) * Math.Log(InitVlaue / (100 - InitVlaue));
        double F = Math.Round((InitVlaue - 0.225) / (0.711 - 0.225), 5);
        double S = Math.Round(((V_Ep) + (F - 1) * V_Et - F * V_En), 5);
        double ceq = Math.Round(F + 1.53 * S, 5);
        return Math.Round(mk * ceq, 3);
    }
```

my view is

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InitVlaue)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InitVlaue,new {style="width:50px;"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InitVlaue)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RegValue)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RegValue,new {style="width:50px;"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RegValue)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InitEnga)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.InitEnga,new {name="initEngaTextBox",style="width:50px;",@readonly="readonly"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InitEnga)
    </div>
```

Iwant when the user type in any of the first 2 fields (`InitVlaue` or `RegValue`)
the filed `InitEnga` get updated
I tried to add the field directly or call the function that does the calculation with no success.
I searched and found 1000's of answers using things like ajax, Knockout ...etc
I have no experince with javascript at all.
Is there a simple way to solve this?

2- in all text box although i specified the format `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}")]` , i still see the value 0 , any idea what is wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Firstly your `DisplayFormatAttribute` is only respected when you use `EditorFor()` and `DisplayFor()` (its not applicable when using `TextBoxFor()`). Second, if you want react to client side events, then you need to use javascript/jquery

Comment: There's no way to achieve this using pure server side MVC. If you want the third value to be recalculated while updating the first two fields dynamically you will need to use javascript. And if the function that performs the calculation is a server side function you will need to send those values to the server which can be achieved with AJAX. So I would recommend you start learning javascript if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: The MVC code in C# is executed on server and not in client. Thus when you change the value for other 2, the third one is not getting updated, since there is no server call being made. 

What you need is simple Javascript which will either do the calculation on the client side or send the changed values back to server and get the updated values and show the updated value in UI. 

Because this looks like simple calculation to me I will recommend doing the calculator on the client with javascript.

Comment: If you can share the internal logic of CommonComputation.CalcuEnga(x,y) function. I can help you create a simple javascript to achieve this on client side

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks!

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thanks

Comment: @Abhimanyu Thanks, but i have no JS experince, i tried to check Jquery but the code doesn't make any sense to me. will have to make sometime to lear it :-)

Comment: @Abhimanyu I added the CommonComputation.CalcuEnga(x,y) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to respond to client side events you need to use javascript/jquery. In your case, by handling the `.change()` event of the textboxes. Start by giving your 2 editable textboxes a class name

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InitVlaue, "{0:#.#}", new { @class="calc" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegValue, "{0:#.#}", new { @class="calc" })
```

Note the second parameter is the format string (the `DisplayFormatAttribute` is only respected by the `EditorFor()` and `DisplayFor()` methods so they can be deleted unless your using those methods elsewhere) and you can now use css to style the width - `.calc { width: 50px; }`

You could do the calculation on the client using javascript, but because it's complex, it would mean maintaining it on both the server and the client, so I suggest that you use ajax to call a server method that performs the calculation and returns the value.

Add the `jquery-{version}.js` to your view (or layout) and add the following script

```
<script>
    var url = '@Url.Action("Calculate", "yourControllerName")';
    $('.calc').change(function() {
        // get the values of the textboxes
        var init = $('#InitVlaue').val();
        var reg = $('#RegValue').val();
        // Check they are valid
        if (init == '' || reg == '' || isNaN(init) || isNaN(reg)) {
            return;
        }
        $.post(url, { initVlaue: init, regValue: reg }, function(response) {
            $('#InitEnga').val(response);
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

and add the following controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Calculate(double initVlaue, double regValue)
{
    var result = CommonComputation.CalcuEnga(initVlaue, regValue);
    return Json(result.ToString("#.#"));
}
```

To learn more about `jQuery`, refer to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: Thanks alot,
if i change to  **Html.EditorFor** the second parameter gives the error **Cannot resolve template {0:#.#}**

Comment: You cannot use `EditorFor()` like that. Just use the code as I gave you, but if you want to use `EditorFor()` then its just `Html.EditorFor(m => m.RegValue)` (and it will use the `DataFormatString` for format the value. But because you not using MVC-5.1+, then you will not be able to add html attributes so its not really suitable in your case

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i followed your step and having the following issues: 1- the field is not filed in but i see number 222 when the form is loaded , the number is added somewhere between 2 fileds, 2- Error regarding IsNaN, but solved using isNaN, **$('#InitVlaue')** is this the textbox id or name? 3- i put a break in the json action but never arrived there

Comment: I'm assuming you have not following the code correctly. I will create a DotNetFiddle for you in about 30 min to show you how it works.

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AndbYX). Note I had a typo - a `val` should have been `var` and `!IsNan` should be `isNaN` (see updated answer). I'm not sure what numbers your entering into the textboxes but I always get `Infinity` as the response. It migh be worth adding other attributes such as `Range` that ensure the user enters a correct value

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to create that, i really appreciate it!
I will have to adapt my code respecting your example

Comment: I also suggest you use `double? InitEnga` (nullable) as per the fiddle and put some check in the `CalcuEnga` to return `null` if the initial values of `InitVlaue` and `RegValue` are `0` (so it does not output NaN in the textbox.

Comment: It works thanks!
one thing i don't undesrstand, how did you manage to give the input textbox a name **InitVlaue** i see you are using **[Display(Name = "Init")]** but when i see my sorce page i still see the **name = CalcuEnga.InitValue** how does the script knows **$('#InitVlaue')**

Comment: The `TextBoxFor()` (and all the `HtmlHelper` methods that generate form controls) add the `id` attribute based on the property name. Always inspect the html that your generating so you get an understanding of what the `HtmlHelper` methods do.

Comment: Note also that you should be using `[Display(Name = "Init")]` not `[DisplayName("Init")]` but the purpose of that attribute is for use in the `LabelFor()` and `DisplayNameFor()` methods. It does not affect the html for form controls.

Comment: Thanks, i'm googling the difference between them.
PS: I tried to move your script to external js then call the js in my view but it didn't work, the reason is because i will use it in both create and edit and i thought it might be more practical to move the script to external js

Comment: The `var url = '@Url.Action("Calculate", "yourControllerName")';` is razor code - it is not parsed in external files. If you want to put the script in an external file, then you need to leave that line in the main view